# stopping when cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a piece of VBA code and I want it to copy a value from a cell when clicking on a cell , but now i want it to do nothing when the cell is empty. The first part works fine, but I haven't got a clue how to make it stop when there is nothing in the cell I click on:
Someone got any good ideas ?

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 'single click version
 
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A5:S29")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False   'clears clipboard and stops cell flashing - like pushing escape key
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Target.Copy Worksheets("SPC").Range("R2")
        Worksheets("SPC").Activate
    Application.Calculate
    End If
 
End Sub
```

I know the function isblank, but don't know how to run that in VBA

Comment: You're looking for `IsEmpty`.

Comment: replace `Else` with `ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Target) Then`

Comment: Super, works perfectly